# Database connection is not working even after providing proper settings in settings.py in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i am trying to connect mysql in one of my django settings and then try to run django-admin db shell in command line but it is not working.
here is my code for settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'investors_data',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and when i am trying to run django-admin dbshell then i am fgetting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Nishant Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 322, in execute
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 195, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 59, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\nishant singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I am getting a similar error when try to run django-admin runserver

Answer (score 0):

To do anything within a project, you should use `manage.py` not `django-admin.py` as it is associated with a specific settings file.

Comment: If i am trying to run my server with python manage.py runserver then i am getting the following error:

    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name 'path'